# How to pay from my paypal account to other user and get response for it

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a site where I get some money from one user's paypal account into my paypal account and get a response for it. It's working perfectly fine with code I got from from [here](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-payment-system-with-paypal_249.html).

Now I want a different scenario. From the admin site I want to make a payment back to my customer as a special discount back offer. When I log in from my account and do the transaction to my customer's account, it shows payment failed. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? What changes have you made to the code to accomplish this?

Comment: Use Express Checkout API and set the Seller Details to the email address you want to send the money to.